# Google Cloud Fleet Routing... what types of VRPs does it cover?

Tags: vehicle-routing, or-tools

I'm familiar with solving VRPs in Google's `ortools`. Has anybody used Google's new Cloud Fleet Routing capability (separate from `ortools`) to solve VRPs and if so, know what types of VRPs can be solved on it? I may soon have a client with a very particular type of VRP that `ortools` doesn't look like it readily covers. As such I'm looking for commercial options.

Comment: As you're looking for VRP variants commercial options, you might want to look at our commerical out of-the-box implementations or build your own using the Timefold open source Solver: [Timefold Vehicle Routing](https://timefold.ai/model/vehicle-routing).

Comment: I see no indication of this service not just being a wrapper (which surely has it's merrits) for the same core solver (the routing-solver of the ortools project). This core-solver is actively developed (not that easy to follow due to their internal-external copybara-based repo-mirroring which basically squashes multiple commits to the routing-solver), by design targeting *rich VRPs* and quite extensible. I don't think they can afford to maintain two solvers for the rich VRP.  From the features mentioned in the accepted answer, i don't see anything special compared to the mentioned solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/google-cloud-optimization-ai-cloud-fleet-routing-api

and

https://cloud.google.com/optimization/docs/reference/rpc

may help. Generally, CFR can solve in addition to VRP with time windows, CFR supports pickup-and-deliveries, pickup alternatives, drivers, breaks, multiple capacity types, incompatibilities, traffic-awareness, auto-grouping of visits, customizable delays, heterogeneous vehicles, and more

Comment: This is helpful. It's a VRP with TW and variable stop times. I'm being asked how they should be changing the TW to improve total time (driving + stop time).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve many kinds of VRPs, with more modelling power than with OR-Tools: VRP, CVRP (capacities), PDP (pickup and delivery), VRPTW (time windows), with breaks, refueling, soft constraints, and probably a zillion others.